# Include Rails config_for settings in rspec helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

Is there a way to include the config_for settings in rspec tests? I have the following settings configured in config/initialisers/settings.rb:

```
SETTINGS = Rails.application.config_for(:settings)
```

but they aren't autoloaded in rspec and it triggers the following:

```
 Failure/Error: generator = SETTINGS['my_strategy'].constantize.new(file)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass
```

As it isn't a module or class, I can't include it in the normal way and doing something as:

```
config.include Rails.application, type: :controller
```

Is in my opinion, not the proper thing to do.

Comment: Whats the actual use case?

Comment: The case is that rspec doesn't autoload the required constants which are normally autoloaded with the Rails::Application, specifically the "config_for" constants.

Comment: Where are this constants defined?

Comment: config/initialisers/settings.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I couldn't find a rspec helper which can load the config_for settings. I solved this by doing the following:

```
before :all do
  SETTINGS['my_strategy'] = 'StrategyClass'
end
```

Which solved the loading of the constant.

Comment: Actually this only solves the use of one constant. And you should be defining each one you need.